# Do browsers validate authenticatorGetAssertion responses in some way before they get sent back to the server?

Tags: webauthn, fido, authenticator

I'm currently writing my own FIDO2 authenticator firmware. Up to this point I've been testing my application with the libfido2 suit. I'm able to create new credentials and assertions using `libfido2-cred` and `libfido2-assert`. I'm also able to create new credentials for test websites like webauthn.io or webauthn.me using Chrome. The problem is that calls to the `assertions.get` API seem to fail quietly.

When I click on login the host first asks for a CID, then he fetches information about the authenticator and finally calls `authenticatorGetAssertion`. The authenticator answers with a `authenticatorGetAssertion` response like

```
a301a26269645840eac3393722c5a48cd0dd61d5d0a24e85930ca125fc6330de7ba790808787c16eefa61932a68d13421e3bb37f2d79fea463becc44d9641eb329db471d649e979b64747970656a7075626c69632d6b657902582574a6ea9213c99c2f74b22492b320cf40262a94c1a950a0397f29250b60841ef04100000009035846304402206c0259d9264817316548f7428fcd4b6d2b6cbbdeabdc3f4b859370fee9a862c5022066c8456ec36d7b64bd06b4157f0238f8f73623b252d67301fb7fbb722c3e7bf0

---

{1: {"id": h'EAC3393722C5A48CD0DD61D5D0A24E85930CA125FC6330DE7BA790808787C16EEFA61932A68D13421E3BB37F2D79FEA463BECC44D9641EB329DB471D649E979B', "type": "public-key"}, 2: h'74A6EA9213C99C2F74B22492B320CF40262A94C1A950A0397F29250B60841EF04100000009', 3: h'304402206C0259D9264817316548F7428FCD4B6D2B6CBBDEABDC3F4B859370FEE9A862C5022066C8456EC36D7B64BD06B4157F0238F8F73623B252D67301FB7FBB722C3E7BF0'}
```

but the browser doesn't send the data back to the server for verification and I don't know why. Does somebody know what could possibly prevent `assertions.get` from sending the response data back to the server?

I compared "my" response data with data generated by a YubiKey and can't see any difference, despite from the signature being different (and the extension (0x04)).

```
a401a262696450c2d80657076c96c11a474700327f902864747970656a7075626c69632d6b657902582574a6ea9213c99c2f74b22492b320cf40262a94c1a950a0397f29250b60841ef0010000000f0358473045022100feabe7198e0a75fb6981f89b2a989b3f422fda862be38ec22e169c798c8d0c98022000bfd5570d63d8a3ce2795cc0b570f6769620bdc779dcb4671245b2bba95905604a16269644e593268796232316c655856696151

---

{1: {"id": h'C2D80657076C96C11A474700327F9028', "type": "public-key"}, 2: h'74A6EA9213C99C2F74B22492B320CF40262A94C1A950A0397F29250B60841EF0010000000F', 3: h'3045022100FEABE7198E0A75FB6981F89B2A989B3F422FDA862BE38EC22E169C798C8D0C98022000BFD5570D63D8A3CE2795CC0B570F6769620BDC779DCB4671245B2BBA959056', 4: {"id": h'593268796232316C655856696151'}}
```

I've analyzed the behavior using Wireshark and Chrome debugging tools.

### Update 07.12.22 #1

Chrome device-log (chrome://device-log)

```
FIDOError[23:33:04] Ignoring status 18 from usb-cafe:4004

FIDOError[23:33:04] -> (rejected CBOR structure) {1: {"id": h'37A12AEF2288D30ADFF41FF13FDCEFEB72364EC1A5DC7B06814CCF6F1646B6AD1C6455D725582935F3321B32AF111FB20D6129E06F1AA320B1675588B8CE3890', "type": "public-key"}, 2: h'74A6EA9213C99C2F74B22492B320CF40262A94C1A950A0397F29250B60841EF04100000007', 3: h'3045022015A60423185E4E7BCC50425502CE86B30A3DEFD4337007BC1ED802CA3456FED6022100CEB329FFDFD878DACBD2311748624B0F44577E66F7D00D08052B13EC1626830E'}

FIDODebug[23:33:04] AdapterDiscoveringChanged() is_scanning=1

FIDODebug[23:33:04] Discovery session started.

FIDODebug[23:33:04] <- 2 {1: "webauthn.io", 2: h'7212A2F6DD50577AB7E2E962537C6BF373DAC511359047128CF4FB803F189511', 3: [{"id": h'37A12AEF2288D30ADFF41FF13FDCEFEB72364EC1A5DC7B06814CCF6F1646B6AD1C6455D725582935F3321B32AF111FB20D6129E06F1AA320B1675588B8CE3890', "type": "public-key"}]}

FIDODebug[23:33:04] The device supports the CTAP2 protocol.

FIDODebug[23:33:04] -> {1: ["FIDO_2_0"], 3: h'FA2B99DC9E3942578F924A30D23C4118', 4: {"rk": false, "up": true, "plat": false}}

FIDODebug[23:33:04] Sending CTAP2 AuthenticatorGetInfo request to authenticator.

FIDODebug[23:33:04] BLE adapter address 00:24:D6:F8:95:57

FIDODebug[23:33:04] Android accessory discovery started

FIDOEvent[23:33:04] Starting GetAssertion flow

FIDODebug[23:33:04] Found 0 caBLEv2 devices

FIDODebug[23:30:00] -> {1: "packed", 2: h'74A6EA9213C99C2F74B22492B320CF40262A94C1A950A0397F29250B60841EF04100000006FA2B99DC9E3942578F924A30D23C4118004037A12AEF2288D30ADFF41FF13FDCEFEB72364EC1A5DC7B06814CCF6F1646B6AD1C6455D725582935F3321B32AF111FB20D6129E06F1AA320B1675588B8CE3890A5010203262001215820CC105C15A0179913C46FFE0974C5D6DAB41AA33CDB247B5C35ED5DB36DC5B039225820889DC50608AA17AC8A792A578E82512872F16DB8979A22A5AE3207A0F76DB4F5', 3: {"alg": -7, "sig": h'30440220452E6EE9ADCD02A56B6C712988D17988C34BA33EF32E5894FCAAD14DBBEBBF90022076F66C66CE1247EAB31067897B488C0B887BF470370AF320403D948FDE125A67'}}

FIDODebug[23:29:59] AdapterDiscoveringChanged() is_scanning=1

FIDODebug[23:29:59] Discovery session started.

FIDODebug[23:29:59] <- 1 {1: h'278AFCA4A91A40C4D081D61D60E9B9C95EE1E81A444AC17EC97AD0D2784F5AAE', 2: {"id": "webauthn.io", "name": "webauthn.io"}, 3: {"id": h'6447687063326C7A5958526C63335178', "name": "thisisatest1", "displayName": "thisisatest1"}, 4: [{"alg": -7, "type": "public-key"}]}

FIDODebug[23:29:59] The device supports the CTAP2 protocol.

FIDODebug[23:29:59] -> {1: ["FIDO_2_0"], 3: h'FA2B99DC9E3942578F924A30D23C4118', 4: {"rk": false, "up": true, "plat": false}}

FIDODebug[23:29:59] Sending CTAP2 AuthenticatorGetInfo request to authenticator.

FIDODebug[23:29:59] BLE adapter address 00:24:D6:F8:95:57

FIDODebug[23:29:59] Android accessory discovery started

FIDODebug[23:29:59] Found 0 caBLEv2 devices

HIDUser[22:58:42] HID device added: vendorId=51966, productId=16388, name='SugarYourCoffee CandyStick FIDO', serial='cafebabe', deviceIds=['/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:CAFE:4004.0018/hidraw/hidraw5'], reportDescriptor='BtDxCQGhAQkCFQAm/wB1CJVAgQIJAxUAJv8AdQiVQJECwA=='

USBUser[22:58:42] USB device added: path=/dev/bus/usb/001/025 vendor=51966 "SugarYourCoffee", product=16388 "CandyStick FIDO", serial="cafebabe", guid=f83734fa-a1ef-45ef-846b-9c9d64f1a9f4

USBUser[22:58:32] USB device removed: path=/dev/bus/usb/001/024 guid=68215484-5c3f-4c3a-b99e-bf75049ee5af

HIDUser[22:58:32] HID device removed: deviceId='/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:CAFE:4004.0017/hidraw/hidraw5'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, open chrome://device-log to see Chrome's debug logging about CTAP2 messages. The errors are not always super-detailed. If it's something generic (like "structural error") then please include the full trace from device-log (i.e. including the getInfo exchange.)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of chrome://device-log. Seems like there is something wrong with the CBOR structure. It's not the ordering of the keys as far as I can judge... Definitely answers the question of whether the browser validates the data.

Comment: I'm eyeballing the hex here, so might be wrong, but it looks like the [flags byte](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#authdata-flags) in the authenticator data is 0x41, which is AT+UP. But AT isn't valid for an assertion response and there's no AT data in the authenticator data, which would cause a structural error.

Comment: You're my savior. Have completely overlooked that I set the AT flag. Thank you so much